# New site --- Fake URLs / Links INDEXED by Google --- WHY?

Tags: spam

Last week we submitted one of our sites (Built on CodeIgniter) to Google Search Console for indexing (including sitemap) and to our surprise we found 5 URLs that are not part of our website at all.

These seem to be SPAM URLs.

They're not part of our sitemap.xml and we've checked the sitemap file itself on the server and it was not compromised.

I noticed that on this account allow_url_include = On > so I've disabled it now.

But we're still getting about one new SPAM Url being indexed each day.

We have our own dedicated server with hardened security so I'm a little confused as to what's happening here...

Has anyone experienced such issue and if so, what was the culprit and how can it be sorted out?

[Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QOKA.jpg)